# Get HTML inside directive declaration

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that can contain some HTML inside it. How can I get it? I have tried link and compile but I am getting the HTML that is defined in the template. Here is my view:

```
<my-directive ng-model="ctrl.SomeField">
   <p> This is the HTML I want! <p>
</my-directive>
```

Here is my directive:

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    ngModel: "="
  },
  template: "<p>This is the HTML that is being returned from compile and link!</p>" + 
            "<p>This is not the HTML that I want!</p>"
  link: {
    pre: function preLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      var html = element.html();  //returns the html in the directive template
    },
    post: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      var html = element.html();  //returns the html in the directive template
    }
  },
  compile: function(element, attrs){
      var html = element.html();  //returns the html in the directive template
  }
}
```

How do I get the HTML from my view and not from my directive template?

Edit: Here is an example - http://plnkr.co/edit/z6gFOrGG01jKoKwISHcW?p=preview

Comment: Try with like console.log(element.find('p')); in the link block

Comment: Doesn't work, still returning the HTML I don't want.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/whisher/3733e1f67e63c798952a it works console.log print This is the HTML I want!

Comment: I don't want to rely on the text being a `p` tag, I would like to put whatever I want in ideally.

Comment: The last try :) try with element.find('*')

Comment: can you elaborate as you why you want the original child HTML when you are using a template in the directive with will replace it? If you are trying to place the original nested HTML something within the template here is an example of doing that: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mayrniii2nYGfKVSjPe9?p=preview

Comment: @Enzey Thanks! That gets me a bit closer. Here is the final issue I am having: http://plnkr.co/edit/OlRyBN1I0jCkAREIKVeC?p=preview. The  list of items makes it into the directive, but isn't being displayed...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution! http://plnkr.co/edit/OlRyBN1I0jCkAREIKVeC?p=preview. Basically I just needed to use another directive to do some fancy transclusion stuff in a link step.

Here is the directive:

```
function returnFn() {
    return {
        link: {
            pre: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
                if (transclude) {
                    transclude(scope, function (clone) {
                        element.append(clone);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return [returnFn];
```